# Dot matrix fast printing with precise layout in Java

Tags: java, printing, reporting, legacy, dot-matrix

I'd like to know what practical way of constructing reports for EPSON Dot Matrix printers exists in Java. At this time, I'm having the LX300+II model to play with.

I know that there are basically two ways of using this printer:

1. As a typewriter, outputting directly raw ASCII data to the parallel port
2. Graphical printing, with graphical fonts and precise positioning.

How can I use both fast printing fonts(provided by **1**) and precise positioning (provided by **2**)?

I know this is possible to do because a couple of years ago, I got to make reports for the EPSON FX 2180 that included drivers with native printing fonts installed in Windows. This allowed to do exactly what I want here.

Now I'm using JasperReports for graphical reporting and works fine, but I do have some reports that *need* to be printed in dot matrix printers and *fast*, too.
What can be an alternative for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would [TextPrinter](http://java4less.com/textprinter/Documentation.html) fit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print fast in dot-matrix printers, you need to do it in "plain-text" mode. The following code works for me:

```
try {
    // LPT1 is the printer port
    try (FileWriter out = new FileWriter("LPT1:")) {
        out.write("String1\nString2\nString3\n");
        out.flush();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: What should I replace the "LPT1:" with? Where should I look for the name?

Answer (score 0):

//java print with printer dot matrix

```
String bill = "your text";

InputStream br = new ByteArrayInputStream(bill.getBytes());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(br));
String line;
//if you use windows
FileWriter out = new FileWriter("////IP Printer//printer name");
//if you use linux you can try SMB:(samba)
while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{  
    System.out.println("line"+line);
    out.write(line);
    out.write(0x0D);  CR
    out.write('\n');
    writer.println(line);
}
out.close();
in.close();
writer.close();
```

//it work for me...